# Earning and spending gold with ReactiveX

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am trying to learn reactive programming with Rx(Js), and making a little cookieclicker-style game at the same time. I want to figure out if Rx is the right fit, so I'm trying to model game events as streams.

First off, there's the income stream, which is really nice to do with RxJs:

```
const click$ = fromEvent($("#clicker"), "click")
const autoclick$ = interval(1000)

const earnedGold$ = merge(click$, autoclick$)
  .map(() => 10)
  .scan((acc, next) => next + acc, 0)
```

This way `earnedGold$` emits the total earned gold (10 per click) for every mouse click and every autoclick. I can add more gold sources as they become available.

The question is: **how to implement spending?**

I have another stream, `purchaseOrders$` that is composed of several different button clicks, and emits objects like this: `{ price: 150, upgrade: { type: "speed", amount: 15 } }`

ISTM I now want to transform this stream into two: a `spentGold$` for prices and `purchases$` for upgrades that are actually purchased. But of course, you can only purchase something if you have enough gold.

How do I get the current gold total? I originally intended to have a `currentGold$` stream that would merge `earnedGold$` with `spentGold$` and emit running total. But it turns out that I would need this `currentGold$` as an input to the decision whether to emit the purchase in the first place?
I could resolve this circular dependency by making the `spentGold$` into a `Subject`, but that a) doesn't seem to be the reactive way, and b) opens a race condition, see below.

Another way is to keep a simple `currentGold` variable and update it from a subscriber to the spending/earning streams. Then when deciding whether to allow a purchase, I could check this variable, emit a purchase and an upgrade.
But, same as the `Subject` solution, this opens a race condition: How can I know that the `currentTotal` is up-to-date WRT queued spends? If I emit a purchase and the subscriber doesn't update the total before I get to the next queued purchase order, I will still be working with the old total.

Of course I could subtract from the total before emitting the purchase, but that possibly opens more race conditions down the road when there are more ways to lose gold.

I could also not allow uncertain "purchase orders" in the first place; the "purchase" button will be disabled if there's not high enough total. But that also seems susceptible to race conditions.

So, what's a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shareReplay(1) to always emit the latest current gold amount, that should besomething you can start off with.

```
const click$ = fromEvent($("#clicker"), "click")
const autoclick$ = interval(1000)

const earnedGold$ = merge(click$, autoclick$)
  .map(() => 10)
  .scan((acc, next) => next + acc, 0)
.shareReplay(1)

const spendGo.d$=earnedGod$.map(...)
```